# Dynamically change scrollEnabled property of UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have an app whis have UITableViewController and by default have scrollEnabled. But in some cases I want to disable scrolling. So I add method

```
- (void)scrollEnable:(BOOL)enable
{
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = enable
    NSLog(enable ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

I make shure that method is trigered when I want to chande scrolling, because I logged in console. But it doesnt make any effect on scrolling. If I set this property to NO in viewDidLoad, the scroll become disabled. But in this method this property dont change anything. I ensure that this method gets called but doesn change anything. Is there any way to dynamically change this property.

So as I use your advice it didnt help. self.tableView is not nil and the method gets called normally. Here is the method:

```
- (void)scrollEnable:(BOOL)enable
{
    if (_enable)
    {
        NSLog(@"ENABLE");
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"DISABLE");
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: this should work. Check if self.tableView is nil or not by printing out the self.tableView variable. Also this shouldn't change it too much, but try [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:enabled];

Comment: as mentioned by @Bergasms , i also recommend trying [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:enabled];

Comment: I logged self.tableView and here is output:<UITableView: 0x201ed000; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2085ad80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2085ac80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> So its not nil.I also modified method like you said.